# Image and print_media_type for pdfkit are not working on rails 4.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have created a pdf using pdfkit.Pdf is created. But the image is not displaying on my pdf and the print_media_type is also not working. I am using rails 4.0.2 and ruby 2.0.0. can anyone please help me to solve this problem? I am attaching details here. Thank you.

**gem file:**

```
gem 'pdfkit','0.5.2'    
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary','0.9.9.1'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-heroku','1.0.0'
```

**application.css :**

```
@media print {
body {    
    text-align: justify;
    font-size:566px;
    background-color: red;
  }  
}
```

**application.rb:**

```
require "pdfkit"    
config.middleware.use PDFKit::Middleware, :print_media_type => true
```

**config/initializers/pdfkit.rb :**

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = 'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
  config.default_options = {
    :page_size => 'A4',
    :page_height => '2478',
    :footer_right => "Page [page] of [toPage]",
    :margin_top=>"0.5in",
    :margin_right=>"1in",
    :margin_bottom=>"0.5in",
    :margin_left=>"1in",
    :zoom => '1.5',
    :disable_smart_shrinking=> false,
    :print_media_type => true
  }
  config.root_url = "//localhost" 
end
```

**application.html.erb:**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>`
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>`
<body>
  <%= image_tag "rails.png", size: "725x150" %>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<img src="<%=root_url%>/rails.png" height="725" width="150" >
```

or

```
<img src="<%=root_url%>/assets/rails.png" height="725" width="150" >
```