# How do I convert HTML to PDF using prawn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an HTML file. I want to convert it to PDF using prawn. Can anyone tell me is this possible?

Comment: You can start by reading this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn?view=asciicast or the revised version if you have a pro account.

Answer (score -2):

We use acts_as_flying_saucer to convert html to pdf: it does a very good job.  It's a wrapper for flying_saucer, which is a free java app that you install on your server and local machine(s).

https://github.com/dagi3d/acts_as_flying_saucer

Answer (score -3):

For that you want either [pdfkit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit) or [WickedPDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) rather than Prawn

Comment: It is also possible with prawn.

Comment: Fair enough.  I didn't know that but I still think that it'd be harder than pdfkit or wickedpdf

Comment: But my pdfkit is not working properly. can you please help me? Its the link...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829538/image-and-print-media-type-for-pdfkit-are-not-working-on-rails-4-0-2